# Is there a QAbstractItemModel type class/interface better suited for key-value data structures?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qabstractitemmodel

`QAbstractItemModel` is very table-oriented, and not <strike>well suited</strike> at all usable to handle data indexed by keys other than row/column numbers.

Is there any way to handle this better than a bunch of `Q_INVOKABLE` functions and custom update handling?

Comment: `QAbstractListModel` with an underlying `QMap` for storage. Keep in mind the map is an ordered container and you can't insert just about anything anywhere willynilly.

Comment: Actually, the question isn't entirely clear. Do you mean map-like in key/value pairs (QMap), or map-like as in geography? Without knowing what you're trying to do, it's difficult to provide assistance. Also, to be more precise, QAbstractItemModel is tree-oriented, not table-oriented. A table is just a simple form of a tree where there are no parents.

Comment: If you want to just store map data (in the sense of key-value pairs), use a `QMap` or `QHash` ... . If you actually want a model for use in a view, what do you expect to see in your view, and in what sense does QAbstractItemModel and its convenience subclasses not suit you?

Comment: I just don't see how the row/column can map to the map's key/value pair, including the inserting and removing rows...

Answer (score 1):

All you need is for the keys to have a [strict total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Strict_total_order). Then there's always a unique 1:1 mapping between the keys and row numbers. And you're done.

The existence of a row/column number doesn't mean that you can't expose a key-value store. Expose the keys and values each in their own column. To efficiently get the index for a given key, you'd want a method like `QModelIndex index(const QVariant &key, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex())`.

Also, given that a `QModelIndex` can store private data, there's nothing precluding you from creating indices that wrap the key value in addition to row/column, if you'd need that value to be bundled with the index for some reason. Note that the persistent index mechanism will work for you as well - as long as you emit the proper row insertion/removal signals as you must anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How could I use this `QAbstractItemModel` when the keys I want to show the Items for are defined in QML? I don't have a `MapView` (cfr. `ListView`) so I don't see how I can bind properly to the `QAbstractItemModel` in this case.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly are you asking for now. Your original question claimed that a `QAbstractItemModel` doesn't work with a key-value data structure. I show how it can be made to work. What else do you need *exactly*? Implementing the model is on you, obviously.

Comment: I wonder what the View will look like. Every QML View I know operates on some table or list based model, even using "model" as a shortcut to an element inside the delegate. I don't see how that would work for a key value model. At all. There seem to be no examples on the Web showing an implementation of a non-standard QML View.

Comment: There's nothing special to be done on the view. The table/list is only an interface that maps 1:1 to a key-value store. The model can be key-value based, because externally they are indistinguishable. If implemented correctly, that is. For example, if you expose keys as column 0, and values as column 1, then you modify the key value, the model will move the row to a proper location based on the key sort order. The views will behave as expected. Etc.

Comment: I think I'm not explaining my predicament clearly: I don't want to show this map in e.g. a ListView. I want to show (some of) its distinct items at specific places that are marked by a map key. I totally get the whole "let's wrap it in a list" thing, but that's not what I want to do.

Comment: Please ask a new question, because what you just said has nothing to do with your question whatsoever. I also have no idea what you mean by  "showing ... at specific places ... that are marked". Perhaps show some QML that demonstrates what sort of an API you'd like to consume.